# Why does a normal distributed curve never touch edges on both sides?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I have observed that the curve of normal distribution never touches the x-axis, but never really got hold of the intuition. Can someone help?

Comment: What's the "curve of normal distribution"? Because I can think of two of those.

Comment: Because there is non-zero probability of having arbitrarily large outliers?

Comment: Do you mean: Why is $e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$ never zero?